# Convert rawstring (Byte String) into readable String

Tags: abap, function-module, sap-data-dictionary

**Requirement:** 
To convert **SRT_MMASTER** table's **MESSAGE_DATA** field data into readable string format or in internal table.

I have tried different function modules to convert Byte String (Blob) data stored in **SRT_MMASTER** table's **MESSAGE_DATA** field but none of it returned readable string format or at least generate an XML file in return.

I have tried **Function modules like** :

```
SCMS_BINARY_TO_STRING, 
SDIXML_XML_TO_DOM, 
SDIXML_DOM_TO_DATA,
SMUM_XML_PARSE
```

**and methods like** :

```
cl_soap_xml_parser=>get_data
cl_soap_xml_parser=>get_formatted_data
CALL METHOD cl_bcs_convert=>raw_to_string
```

and more, but none were able to convert it to correct readable format.

Can you suggest which function module or class/method can be used to solve the purpose?

Comment: Can you describe what "SRT_MMASTER table's MESSAGE_DATA" is made of, and what it contains? And for a given example, what output do you expect?

Comment: could you please add a minmal example record from the table?

Comment: @SandraRossi, SRT_MMASTER-MESSAGE_DATA field's Datatype is RAWSTRING (Byte String [BLOB])

Comment: Based on your comments on Haojie answer (which I tested and which answers your question), it seems that you are looking for something else so can you ask a new question to tell what exactly you are looking for? (seems to be more than the field MESSAGE_DATA of database table SRT_MMASTER)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IMPORT` from [DATA BUFFER](http://DATA:%20%20%20lt_message_item%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20TYPE%20srt_persistency_item_t,%20%20%20lx_message_data%20TYPE%20xstring.%20%20SELECT%20SINGLE%20message_data%20FROM%20srt_mmaster%20INTO%20lx_message_data.%20%20IMPORT%20message_data%20=%20lt_message_item%20FROM%20DATA%20BUFFER%20lx_message_data.) and cl_soap_xml_helper=>xstring_to_string

```
DATA:
     lt_message_item        TYPE srt_persistency_item_t,
     lx_message_data TYPE xstring.

SELECT SINGLE message_data FROM srt_mmaster INTO lx_message_data.

IMPORT message_data = lt_message_item FROM DATA BUFFER lx_message_data.

DATA(lv_string) = cl_soap_xml_helper=>xstring_to_string(  lt_item[ 1 ]-value ).
```

Comment: Thanks Haojie. But the value column returned is still in XSTRING format and not in readable format.

Comment: the value is in the lt_message_item. I tested and it should work.

Comment: Yes. And the lt_message_item-value field is still in XSTRING. The other columns like URI and Name are correct. Actually am seeing the value in debugging. Do I need to check it any other way?

Comment: please try cl_soap_xml_helper=>transform_bxml_to_xml for the value field.

Comment: please try cl_soap_xml_helper=>transform_bxml_to_xml for the value field.

Comment: I tried this as well but in debugging it converts Xstring to Xstring which returns the same value. I am not sure if this is the problem in debugging only. My purpose is to read through the data and find the error message and use it for reporting purpose. Hence I need it to be converted into readable format.

Comment: sorry. it should be cl_soap_xml_helper=>XSTRING_TO_STRING. i just tried and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Haojie You were not wrong with `cl_soap_xml_helper=>transform_bxml_to_xml` because it depends what type of line is to be decoded (cf code inside method `GET_MESSAGE_PAYLOAD` of class `CL_SOAP_DB_RUNTIME`). I think that the question should indicate what means "readable format", what expects the OP?

Comment: @SandraRossi, I have updated the title now. But my requirement was already highlighted in the details section of the question.

Comment: @Haojie, Thanks. The solution worked for me. Can you update your answer with the above suggestion about the class and method to convert the data? I will definitely mark the answer as Useful but adding the above code will help others looking for the solution. :) Cheers! CJ